# Prevent PGFplots from using 10^notation on y-axis

Tags: pgfplots

I want the y-axis labels to be labeled 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10,000, …

PGFplots insists on keeping the `10^`-notation in the following minimal example.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
grid=both,
major grid style={black!50},xlabel={x},ylabel={y}]

\addplot[only marks, mark size=4pt,mark=triangle,fill,black] coordinates{
(0.000001, 13.5e3)
(0.0000024, 11.975e3)
(0.004, 4340)
(1 , 3840)
(10  , 2550)
(100 ,  2357)
(257, 2290)
(315, 2280)};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/how-to-prevent-pgfplots-from-using-the-10n-notation-for-axis-ticks?rq=1 (Edit: Sorry, that was perhaps not so relevant.)

Comment: The ticks from log axes are typeset a little bit differently and in fact have two to three options (the base, the exponent itself and how the exponent is typeset). That is related: [Having tick labels like 1, 10, 10^2, 10^3,](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94228)

Comment: There's an option for that: `log ticks with fixed point`, see e.g. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141535/7279).

Comment: @TomBombadil Which is unfortunately not listed in the Ticks chapter of the manual …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: It's in the number formatting section (which makes sense in a way, since it doesn't affect the placement of the ticks, only the formatting of the numbers)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I only know of this since last week, and stumbled upon it by mere accident ;)

Comment: @TomBombadil Very well, I usually just Ctrl+F the manual until I found something or my head starts to spin, whatever comes first. :)

Comment: If Jake's answer below solved your problem you could consider accepting his answer, by clicking on the checkmark just to the left of the answer. This marks the question as solved, and awards some points to both him and yourself.

Answer (score 9):

To have both axes in logarithmic scale, but print the labels for only one of them in fixed point format, you can use the approach from [pgfplots log ticks with fixed point: only for one axis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139079/pgfplots-log-ticks-with-fixed-point-only-for-one-axis):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  log x ticks with fixed point/.style={
      xticklabel={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      }
  },
  log y ticks with fixed point/.style={
      yticklabel={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      }
  }
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
log y ticks with fixed point,
ytick={2000,4000,8000,16000},
grid=both,
major grid style={black!50},xlabel={x},ylabel={y}]

\addplot[only marks, mark size=4pt,mark=triangle,fill,black] coordinates{
(0.000001, 13.5e3)
(0.0000024, 11.975e3)
(0.004, 4340)
(1 , 3840)
(10  , 2550)
(100 ,  2357)
(257, 2290)
(315, 2280)};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution worked -- once I commented out \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

Comment: You should set that to whatever version you're using, it makes new features available.